# Dell Inspiron 8600 pae?

Tags: pae

I have a Dell Inspiron 8600 laptop that is running Windows XP (SP3) that I dug out of my attic the other night. It will boots up, lasts about 5 minutes (only for one user account). Then it pops and reboots. I'm try to install Ubuntu 15.10 (32-bit) on it as my new operating system. When I boot from my Ubuntu 15.10 disc (It works) it shows the Ubuntu loading screen then goes and says "WARNING: PAE disabled. Use parameter 'forcepae' to enable at your own risk! This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:
pae
Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.' I googled around and it seems pae gives you extra memory. I'm scared to enable this because I dont want to screw my computer up. Should I enable pae?

Comment: "This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU: pae Unable to boot- please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU" You CPU does not support PAE, you can `force PAE` as it says, you porberbly should not do this. PAE lets a 32bit OS use more than 4GB of RAM it does not give you extra memory, you only have 512mb of RAM, you don't need PAE at all.

Comment: I suggest installing antix:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/antix-linux/files/Final/MX-14.4/MX-14.4-non-pae.iso/download

Answer (score 1):

The generic default kernel (in 12.10 and onwards) already has PAE enabled.  Therefore I don't see it as being a risky thing to do.  Just grab the most up-to-date version of Ubuntu and enjoy.

Source: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PAE/Enabling

According to a commenter, this machine only has 512 MB of RAM available to it.  Physical Address Extension is only useful if you have more than 4 GB of RAM

Source: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Comment: After Googling the OP laptop, they only have 512mb of RAM and therefore should not force PAE as it is in no way beneficial and may cause issues.

Comment: Please don't think im saying your answer is wrong, you should leave it here as for others this will be useful :) Here is OP specs http://www.engadget.com/products/dell/inspiron/8600/specs/

Comment: I did leave the original reply intact, just appended additional information to make it more useful to the OP and to other readers who have similar questions.